# Adding a trailing slash after adding www and removing .php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, friendly-url

I have a site with pages like about.php, contact.php and test.php?id=xyz.

I added the below redirect for making it seo friendly.

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.krishibazar\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.krishibazar.org/$1 [R=301,L]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

This gives me

```
mydomain.com                      =>  www.mydomain.com
mydomain.com/about.php            =>  www.mydomain.com/about
mydomain.com/test.php?id=12       =>  www.mydomain.com/test?id=12
mydomain.com/about/               =>  CSS Error
```

It is working perfectly fine except if i add a trailing slash at the last its giving error. So either suggest me to prevent the error or adding a trailing slash.

Comment: add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: This worked for me as well except now about and about/ both are opening. It might create SEO duplicates. What do you say ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1: Get rid of the slashes (good for SEO)

How about an additional rule to just handle URL with trailing slashes?

I would place it between the `externally` and `internally` redirects above, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

That should redirect all URL to their slash-free version before they are rewritten to the PHP file.

## Option 2: Fix your CSS

I suppose you are referencing your stylesheet relatively, like

```
<style href="css/style.css" />
```

You might change it to an absolute reference

```
<style href="/css/style.css" />
```

And it should work regardless of the assumed directory depth (denoted by slashes in the URL).

## Conclusion

I would go for option 1 in this case, as it provides a single URL for all pieces of content, which is preferrable in my opinion.

Comment: First one worked flawlessly for me. Thanks @Jan for your conclusion which helped me in deciding the best.

Comment: I noticed s a serious problem after adding the above htaccess code. All my Ajax scripts in the pages stopped working. After removing the htaccesss file its working. Can it be solved ?

Comment: What do those AJAX URL look like?

Comment: $.ajax({
        url:"verify.php", //the page containing php script
        type: "POST", //request type
  data: { type: "send", to: "<?php echo $user;?>"},
        success:function(result){
         alert(result);

Comment: Is the call redirected to `/verify`, being caught be the rule `# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file`?

Comment: I think not.. Only POST ajax request faced problems, i fixed it by converting to GET. All working fine now. Thanks a lot.